# Deployment of a spring boot application on AWS EB with RDS

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

New to AWS EB and RDS.

My spring boot app is currently having one profile of datasource to connect to the local mysql. I have initialised the RDS and configured RDS endpoint in my local profile before packaging. Maven packaging fails because it runs test with the production datasource in local.

I could see below solutions to the issue, but not tried.

1. Should I skip the test phase in maven packaging phase?
2. Should I build the package with local datasource, and will define db configuration in AWS environment? (Do AWS EB environment variables override spring datasource variables?)
3. Should I define two profiles for datasource (ex. dev, prod) and on AWS EB environment set the "prod" profile active?

Please advice me with the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Should I skip the test phase in packaging?

My preferences goes toward making your test phase environment independent, so it does not make a different to build for Dev, Test or Prod.

2. Should I build the package with local datasource, and will define db configuration in AWS environment? (Do AWS EB environment variables override spring datasource variables?)
3. Should I define two profiles for datasource (ex. dev, prod) and on AWS EB environment set the "prod" profile active?

2 + 3 My preference goes to have packages that are not bound to an environment, and use a tool like Puppet to inject the environment specific configuration during deployment.